# Setting up a workspace for Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

What I am trying to do is setup a workspace to test out/view my themes that I am creating for Wordpress. I want to be able to leave it in my Mac computer so I can edited with my IDE and run it when I'm done editing the files. I don't what to publish it on the web I just want to view it locally. 
I found this [MAMP guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP) in the Wordpress website but I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: I don't know about MAMP but you *do* need a webserver capable of running PHP and MySQL.

Comment: You can enable OSX Apache and install MySQL by your own, but MAMP is the easiest/fastest way. Once you have it running, there's no looking back.

Comment: Thanks for the help. By all means I'm not new to coding but when it comes to server stuff I have no idea. It looks like MAMP or Bitnami is the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try Bitnami wordpress stack: http://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress It's one-click-install-everything sort of thing. Disclaimer: I have used it only on Linux, but I'm willing to bet it works the same on other OS.

Comment: The site you link to has a "Download on the Mac App Store" button, so your bet is probably safe :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for a way to create / edit WordPress themes on your computer without installing a web server such as MAMP?

Unfortunately there is no way around it. I had a look at the guide you provided in your question and this is the only way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a server to run your PHP and MySQL — I think MAMP *is* the easy option. Simple to set up and it will make editing your Wordpress sites offline fast.

It'll be slightly more complicated to migrate files from your local install to your production server, but there are many resources available such as the [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server) or [tutorials](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/hosting/migrating-a-wordpress-site-from-a-local-server-to-production/).

You'll get the hang of it after a couple installs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new service, that allows launching WordPress development instances and coding straight from the browser. It is in closed beta now, you can find it at https://wpide.net, it seems they will launch soon.